# Align picture to the right

Tags: graphics, captions, koma-script

Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline,
    justification=raggedleft,
    singlelinecheck=false,
    labelfont=bf,
    font=small}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[H]
    \raggedleft
    \begin{minipage}{20cm}
        \floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,center},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
        {\caption{Some caption that spans more than a line and some additional text}}
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get

[image]

As you can see from the command `\raggedleft` in the code, I was expecting a result which is more like this

[image]

How do I achieve this? Also, although this code works perfectly with `article` class, but if I switch to `scrartcl` the compilation process encounters some trouble unless I remove `labelsep=newline` option for `caption` package. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to align the image to the right margin, you might want to use `foatrow`'s `\floatsetup[figure]{margins=raggedleft}`  command. You can either use it globally by putting it into the preamble or locally as shown in teh following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline,
    justification=raggedleft,
    singlelinecheck=false,
    labelfont=bf,
    font=small}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
{\floatsetup[figure]{margins=raggedleft}
\begin{figure}[H]
        \floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,center},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
        {\caption{Some caption that spans more than a line and some additional text}}
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}}
\end{figure}}

\begin{figure}[H]
        \floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,center},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
        {\caption{Some caption that spans more than a line and some additional text}}
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Regarding switching from `article` to `scrartcl` you will recieve the following error message:

> Package `caption` Error: The option `labelsep=newline` does not work
>   with `\setcaphanging` (which is set by default).

Looking through the `caption` manual, we can find that the default `format` of `article` and `scrartcl` differ:

[image]

By adding `format=plain` to the `\captionsetup` command, we can make the code compilable for `scrartcl` as well. Nevertheless, I'd suggest to take a look at the KOMA-script documentation as these document classes already offer ways to customize the look of captions.

Answer (score 3):

Only as a supplement to the [answer of @leandris](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508629/43317) for the KOMA-Script part: The KOMA-Script class provides environments `captionbeside` and `captionofbeside`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}% if position H is really needed

\KOMAoption{captions}{nooneline,centeredbeside,leftbeside}
\setcapindent*{0pt}
\setcaptionalignment{r}
\renewcommand\captionformat{}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{captionbeside}
      {Some caption that spans more than a line and some additional text}%
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
  \end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{captionbeside}
      {Some caption that spans more than a line and some additional text}%
      [l]% caption position
      [\dimexpr9cm+10pt\relax]% width of caption and figure
      [\dimexpr\linewidth-9cm-10pt\relax]% offset
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
  \end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Warning: Package `floatrow` breaks environment `captionbeside`.